# Cast context into call back interface type from non activity class

Tags: java, android, callback, android-context

> Note! This issue is now resolved, But still wonder How? Please explain?

These are my call back function which is being referenced in setter method of Custom adapter `GridCartAdapter` declaring in activity class.

```
gridCartAdapter.setOnDeleteCartItem(ProductListActivity.this);
gridCartAdapter.setOnAddCartItems(ProductListActivity.this);
```

here is defination for interface function in `GridCartAdapter`

```
public void setOnAddCartItems(OnAddCartItems onAddCartItems)
{
    this.onAddCartItems = onAddCartItems;
}
public void setOnDeleteCartItem(onDeleteCartItem onDeleteCartItem) {
    this.onDeleteCartItem = onDeleteCartItem;
}
```

so if I do same work in non activity class like this

```
gridCartAdapter.setOnDeleteCartItem((onDeleteCartItem)context);
gridCartAdapter.setOnAddCartItems((OnAddCartItems)context);
```

It gives an error of `java.lang.ClassCastException: pk.wiseapps.wisemart.app.activity.SpecificProductActivity cannot be cast to pk.wiseapps.wisemart.app.onDeleteCartItem`

> Jus change this into my code

```
if(context instanceof onDeleteCartItem){
gridCartAdapter.setOnDeleteCartItem((onDeleteCartItem)context);
}
if(context instanceof OnAddCartItems){
gridCartAdapter.setOnAddCartItems((OnAddCartItems)context);
}
```

enter code here

Comment: it is complaining about `SpecificProductActivity` but you are passing `ProductListActivity`. Btw, the error means that `SpecificProductActivity` is not implementing `onDeleteCartItem`

Comment: This works fine in activity class as I described above, but giving an error in non activity class
 'public class CartHandler implements OnAddCartItems, onDeleteCartItem'

Comment: @Blackbelt This works fine after some edition, edition are updated in question posted